# Finding good questions to answer.. about to give up.

Tags: discussion

Click Next... next ... next ... next ... I must be doing something wrong.

I'm looking for good recent questions to answer.

One thought came to mind...

Is there a way to filter questions by the reputation of the poster?

Or some other way to get to the "Good stuff"?

Comment: I'm someone whose questions you'd probably skip and leave with an "ugh, just read the documentation". But you shouldn't. Once upon a time, I wasn't a great python developer. Then, as time went by, I became well versed in ML / ctypes / win32api and some lower level stuff. At that point, I remembered the early days when I was a noob. I wish I had somebody to answer my crappy questions. So, in my opinion, I understand most questions are boring, but if they're good questions, you should answer. One day, that somebody might just become a core developer and ask the "hard" questions :)

Answer (score 9):

The **[Unanswered](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/unanswered)** list is ordered by question upvotes. Answers on these question tend to get a lot attention, and if they're good, quite some upvotes. This is probably the best way to find challenging questions.

Answer (score 9):

I like to use the advanced search, usually something like this:

`is:question closed:no answers:0` [link to query](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=is%3Aquestion%20closed%3Ano%20answers%3A0)

Will get you roughly ~11,000 questions where you can sort by newest or by the amount of votes. Newest may help to give you faster rep since the user is more likely to answer inquiries and mark when the correct answer is given. By votes is likely to get you the most rep if you can produce an informative answer with substance.

To add to some advanced search suggestions, you may also ignore (minus) any questions with tags you don't want to see, such as:

- `-[plugin-*]` remove any questions tagged as a plugin specific question.
- `-[multisite]` ignore any multisite questions.
- etc.

Example: `is:question closed:no answers:0 -[multisite] -[plugin-*]`

The reverse is also true if you want only questions that deal (are tagged) with `[wp-query]`

Example: `is:question closed:no answers:0 [wp-query] -[plugin-*]`